# What happens when rollback() fails for a transaction in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, rollback

```
try
{
    Connection conn = ... MySQL connection ...;
    conn.setAutoCommit(false); // transaction starts
    .... do something ....
}
catch (MySQLException e)
{
    try {
        conn.rollback();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // What happens now?
    }
}
```

For MySQL server (InnoDB Engine), what happens if rollback() fails for a transaction? (i.e. <strike>network goes down right while rollback() is running</strike>, etc...)

Does it mean that DB remains corrupted, or is there any way for MySQL server to recover from "unfinished" rollbacks?

Comment: If network goes down, that means rollback request didn't reach MySQL server, isn't it? Then whatever changes happened, they will stay there. I hope you read the documentation "This method should be used only when auto-commit mode has been disabled."

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that this is a transaction (autocommit = false). Sorry about that.

Comment: If this is a transaction then all actions within the transaction will only be commited once you... Well... `.commit()`. Hopefully, [since you are using MySQL](http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else)... If you can, switch to PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am not interested in commit(). I am curious what happens when rollback() fails, and how it affects the integrity of MySQL DB (does it remain corrupted? or does it have a mechanism to recover from incomplete rollback)

Comment: If your connection goes down, the database server will roll back your transactions.

Comment: What if DB fails to rollback the transaction for some reason other than a network issue?

Comment: @immibis: Your comment make sense, Could you provide a reference? Curious to look at reference.

Comment: @fge ANY engine can fail to rollback even if the chances are slim. What if there is a physical failure (i.e. harddisk failure) while DB server is trying to roll back? I am just asking whether there is any recovery mechanism in place in case of these kind of errors happen.

Answer (score 10):

> Does it mean that DB remains corrupted

Note that at no point in your code snippet has the DB *become* corrupted.  It's simultaneously keeping track of both the original state of the data and the changes you're making in your transaction.

Exceptions raised by `rollback()` are for the client's benefit, not the server. A network outage while trying to rollback triggers an exception so that the client can try to handle it, and because there's no use in proceeding normally.  From the server's perspective a rollback is an explicit instruction to discard the contents of the transaction.  If the rollback command never reaches the database, the database will simply hold off on committing the changes until it decides it's no longer needed, at which point the changes will be purged to clear up memory or disk space in the server.

If you haven't seen it before, you're probably looking for the term [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID); this describes how databases and other concurrent systems have to be designed to mitigate these sort of failures.  An ACID-compliant database is intended to remain consistent even if there is a physical failure midway through the commit or rollback - the final step to commit the change (inside the DB) should be atomic, so that either it succeeds, or is discarded.

---

As a tangential example, [Mercurial](https://mercurial.selenic.com/) has a similar concern regarding ensuring commits never leave [the repo](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Repository) in an inconsistent state.  When a user commits a change, updates need to be written to multiple files, and any one of those writes could fail.  So it does these writes in a careful order to ensure inconsistencies are avoided.

1. First the individual file diffs are appended to their associated revlog files in the repo, associated with a changeset ID.
2. Then the manifest listing these changes is updated, again tied to the changeset ID.
3. Only once all of the above operations have succeeded is the changeset ID itself recorded in the changelog (which is a single atomic write).  If this write succeeds, the commit has succeeded.

If Mercurial comes across an unknown changeset ID in the revlog or manifest files, it ignores it; thereby ensuring a change is either fully committed or not at all.

<sub>It's been a while since I've poked around at the Mercurial internals, it's entirely possible I got some of this muddled, but the gist is correct.</sub>